# jasmine seems doesn't support mock the clock for setImmediate

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine

Here are my tests:

For `setTimeout`, `jasmine.clock()` and `jasmine.clock().tick(...)` works fine.

`index.ts`:

```js
import * as mod from './mod';

export function main() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    mod.foo();
  }, 10);
}
```

`mod.ts`:

```js
export function foo() {}
```

`index.spec.ts`:

```js
import { main } from './';
import * as mod from './mod';

fdescribe('setImmediate', () => {
  beforeEach(function() {
    jasmine.clock().install();
  });

  afterEach(function() {
    jasmine.clock().uninstall();
  });
  it('should pass', () => {
    const fooSpy: jasmine.Spy = spyOn(mod, 'foo').and.stub();
    main();
    jasmine.clock().tick(10);
    expect(fooSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
});
```

Unit test results:

```sh
HeadlessChrome 73.0.3683 (Mac OS X 10.13.6): Executed 1 of 4 (skipped 3) SUCCESS (0.029 secs / 0.004 secs)
TOTAL: 1 SUCCESS
TOTAL: 1 SUCCESS
TOTAL: 1 SUCCESS
```

If replace `setTimeout` with `setImmediate`, the unit test fails.

`index.ts`:

```js
import * as mod from './mod';

export function main() {
  setImmediate(() => {
    mod.foo();
  });
}
```

Unit test results:

```sh
HeadlessChrome 73.0.3683 (Mac OS X 10.13.6) setImmediate should pass FAILED
        Error: Expected spy foo to have been called once. It was called 0 times.
            at <Jasmine>
            at UserContext.<anonymous> (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/src/tests/setImmediate/index.spec.ts:16:20)
            at ZoneDelegate../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:391:1)
            at ProxyZoneSpec.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js.ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js:308:1)
HeadlessChrome 73.0.3683 (Mac OS X 10.13.6): Executed 1 of 4 (1 FAILED) (0 secs / 0.104 secs)
HeadlessChrome 73.0.3683 (Mac OS X 10.13.6) setImmediate should pass FAILED
        Error: Expected spy foo to have been called once. It was called 0 times.
            at <Jasmine>
            at UserContext.<anonymous> (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/src/tests/setImmediate/index.spec.ts:16:20)
            at ZoneDelegate../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:391:1)
HeadlessChrome 73.0.3683 (Mac OS X 10.13.6): Executed 1 of 4 (1 FAILED) (skipped 3) (0.136 secs / 0.104 secs)
TOTAL: 1 FAILED, 0 SUCCESS
TOTAL: 1 FAILED, 0 SUCCESS
TOTAL: 1 FAILED, 0 SUCCESS
```

I found a related issue: https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/issues/866, but the issue is a little outdated and there is no answer for it.

My test environment is angular 8.x using `ng test` command. I don't think this issue is related to the test environment. And the versions of node modules:

```
    "jasmine-core": "^3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "^4.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^3.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.1",
```